# How to access child page components from parent page router links in Angular 6

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular6

In app.component.html, I have a top menu bar which contains 3 links
named as Home, About and contactus.
If I click a home link then I should show leftmenubar of Home page(Home.component.html)
If I click about link then I should show leftmenubar of About page(About.component.html)
so my question is "How to access the Home page, about page divs i.e leftmenubar from my main page(app.component) image button click.

app.component.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark mb-5">
  <img src="src/assets/images/ham1.png" (click)="ShowLeftMenubar();">
 <div class="navbar-nav">
   <a class="nav-item nav-link" routerLink="homepage">Home</a>
<a class="nav-item nav-link active" routerLink="aboutpage">ABOUT</a>
 <a class="nav-item nav-link active" routerLink="contactpage">CONTACTUS</a>
</div>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Home.component.html

```
<div id="leftmenubar"  class="leftmenuclass">
  <a routerLink="showcontent">sample1 </a>
  <a routerLink="showcontent">sample2 </a>
  <a routerLink="showcontent">sample3 </a>
</div>
```

aboutpage.component.html

```
<div id="leftmenubar"  class="leftmenuclass">
  <a routerLink="showcontent">sample3 </a>
  <a routerLink="showcontent">sample4 </a>
  <a routerLink="showcontent">sample5 </a>
</div>
```

Comment: What's not working, if you route it to homepage, then it'lll work no problem here. do you face any issue

Comment: please add routing configuration

Comment: Routing works perfectly. When I click the image button
from my app.component, the div(leftmenubar) in home page should hide. Similarly, if I click the image button in my app.component, then it should show leftmenubar(div) on the home page.

Comment: I hope your get solved by creating a Service with Subject. Check my answee.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a `Subject` in a service myservice.service.ts as follows:

In your myservice.service.ts

```
public sidebar$ = new Subject<boolean>();
```

In your app.component.ts, import the myservice in the constructor then create a flag as follows:

```
public isShowMenu = true;
constructor(private myservice: MyService){}
```

When the user clicks the image

```
ShowLeftMenubar() {
  this.isShowMenu = !this.isShowMenu;
  this.myservice.sidebar$.next(this.isShowMenu);
}
```

In your home.component.ts and about.component.ts, you should listen for the Subject using subscribe method inside the ngOnInit

```
public isShowSidebar = false;
constructor(private myservice: MyService){}
ngOnInit() {
  this.myservice.sidebar$.subscribe((value) => this.isShowSidebar = value);
}
```

In home.component.html and about.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="isShowSidebar" id="leftmenubar"  class="leftmenuclass">
  <a routerLink="showcontent">sample1 </a>
  <a routerLink="showcontent">sample2 </a>
  <a routerLink="showcontent">sample3 </a>
</div>
```

Comment: WOW. Great Answer, I am Happy Nithi, It works,Thanks.

Comment: Whether can i access child component div id(i.e leftmenubar) and class leftmenuclass from my parent component(i.e app.component)